Функиция на питоне и aiogram
Не могу справиться с такой проблемой, создал в файле проверку на логин check_login_unique:
Добавляем пользователя
def add_user(self, user_id, login, password):
    # Проверяем уникальность логина
    if not self.check_login_unique(login):
        return False  # Возвращаем False, если логин уже занят
    with self.connect:
        try:
            self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (user_id, login, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (user_id, login, password))
            self.connect.commit()  # Сохраняем изменения
            print("Пользователь успешно добавлен в базу данных.")
            return True  # Возвращаем True, если пользователь успешно добавлен
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Ошибка при добавлении пользователя: {e}")
            return False  # Возвращаем False в случае ошибки. 

Далее, у меня есть файл с регистрацией для пользователя, и у меня в этом файле не подсвечивается функция которую я добавил
Проверяем уникальность логина
if not await db.check_login_unique(login):  # Обратите внимание на использование await
    await message.answer("Данный логин уже занят. Пожалуйста, выберите другой логин:")
    return

Базу данных подключаю через SQLiteStudio назвал ее userbase (но нету .db приписке к файлу)
У меня есть телеграмм бот, я решил попробовать подключить бд через SQLiteStudio, прописал проверки для бд файл db.py, потом подключаю бд в файл registration.py через from basebd import db и у меня модуль db.check_login_unique(login) показывается что он не рабочий. Если нужна подробная обратная связь буду рад ответить
В чём может быть проблема, не могу очень долго решить и запутался. Благодарю

Ничего не понятно, что такое check_login_unique и почему что-то где-то должно подсвечиваться?

А вы уверены что sqlite поддерживает асинхронку?

Я вообще не понял о какой проблеме речь.

У меня есть телеграмм бот, я решил попробовать подключить бд через SQLiteStudio, прописал проверки для бд файл db.py, потом подключаю бд в файл registration.py через from basebd import db и у меня модуль  db.check_login_unique(login) показывается что он не рабочий.
Если нужна подробная обратная связь буду рад ответить

Что такое "показывается что он не рабочий" и почему вы решили что что-то где-то должно показываться?
